# Converting a .py file to .exe in python 3.8.2

Tags: python, exe

I know this is a commonly asked question but I'm at my wits end.  I've tried both of the most obvious options, pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe and both have given me different errors or the exes haven't worked.

I've tried fixing the problems they gave, but then I saw that pyinstaller might not work on 3.8.

I just need to know if this is even possible right now, and some easy ways to do it, if there are any.

Its been hours of fruitless googling and I just want a concrete answer, even if its a resounding no.

Comment: I would stick with python 3.7 if 3.8 hasn't any advantages for you. Just try to make an exe of a simple program first to see if that works. Examples for 'how to' enough to be found.

Comment: If you show us the error from pyinstaller, we can try to fix it.